# Calling Methods with same name

Tags: java

I have 3 methods, all with the same name.

```
//method 1
public Double x(String x){ }

//method 2
public Double x(Double x){ }

//method 3
public Double x(double x){ }
```

I have some code in Method 1 and I want to call method 3.

Now having `x(new Double(variable));` in method 1 passes the variable to method 2.
This is correct. However I want to now do the same with method 3 (take variable from method 1 and pass to method 3). How would I do this?

Comment: Double.parseDouble(x) where x is from method 1 -does this work for you?

Answer (score 4):

The method that will be executed is defined by the parameter you're calling it with.

simply cast or parse the values.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke it with:

```
return x(Double.parseDouble(x));
```